# Defining roles post Google SSO in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemented Google SSO in my Spring Boot application and now need to make certain people admins while everybody else is a user. In the returned google user object, it doesn't explicitly send the username (just the email) but I have tried passing both as arguments to `withUser()` and it doesn't seem to work.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser(<username>).authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
    }
```

Anyone know if there's another way to do this? Thanks a bunch!

PS: I'm basically following this guide right here: http://www.techforumist.com/google-oauth2-login-in-spring-boot-and-angularjs so you can see what the code looks like.

Comment: what is `Google SSO`? SSO for G suite?

Comment: SSO = Single Sign On. Sorry about that!